# Can't connect to django website started on VPS

Tags: python, django, server

I have tried to start server with Django project like this:
`python3.4 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
and like this:
`python3.4 manage.py runserver my_domain.com:8000`
and it starts fine but I can't visit my site. Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: Perhaps your firewall is blocking port 8000. However, **you should not be using `runserver` in production**. See the [deployment docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/) for how to deploy Django properly.

Comment: @Alasdair> Well, you're right, though it has the side effect of blocking external access (for a regular user who doesn't hand-craft his requests or play `/etc/hosts` tricks). But it's only a side-effect, it's not a full block and my comment is wrong in a misleading way, I'm removing it. Still, it's probably what's preventing OP from accessing his debug server.

Answer (score 3):

The command `python manage.py runserver` is thought for development purposes.
If you have in mind to have a python (django in this case) website running in a remote server, try having a look at [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#the-uwsgi-project).
It's an application server that plays really well with nginx.

Then, it could be possible run your site using the wsgi file in your django project:

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite.wsgi
```

In order to configure your django site, follow [this](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) documentation.

Also, if you plan to host more than one website, uwsgi has a [emperor](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Emperor.html) mode with slightly different configuration, but really worth for your VPS memory.